# Are int main() and int main(void) equivalent prototypes in C23?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, function-prototypes, c23

C23 introduced new semantics in function declarators:

> **6.7.6.3 Function declarators**
>
> [...]
>
> 13   For a function declarator without a parameter type list: the effect is as if it were declared with a parameter type list consisting of the keyword `void`. A function declarator provides a prototype for the function.

This seems to imply that a function definition with an empty parameter list can be written equivalently with `()` or `(void)`.

Yet this equivalence does not seem guaranteed for the `main` function:

> **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup**
>
> The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent or in some other implementation-defined manner.

This does not seem to guarantee that `int main() { /* ... */ }` is a valid definition for `main`, or does *equivalent* cover this variant?

---

It troubles me that the 2 examples in C17 that use the syntax `int main()` (in 6.5.3.4 and 6.7.6.3) have been changed to use `int main(void)` in the latest C23 draft.

Comment: On many traditional Unix systems, you can also declare `main` as `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)`, in which case `envp` is a `NULL`-terminated array of environment variable definitions.  I just tried this on my Linux system, and it still works.  Not sure what ANSI C has to say about it.  It's probably considered non-standard.

Comment: @TomKarzes: this is covered by *or in some other implementation-defined manner*

Comment: The old wording in C11 §6.7.6.3 p14 was *"An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the function has no parameters."* So a **definition** of `main` as `int main() { /*code here*/ }` has been equivalent to `int main(void) { /*code here*/ }` at least as far back as C11.

Comment: @user3386109: That's not how GCC or clang treats it with `-std=c11`.  https://godbolt.org/z/5zf1dr1dK shows GCC accepting `main(123)` after an `int main(){}` definition with no warnings even at `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.  Clang warns about deprecation but doesn't error, with the message saying it's only an error in C2x.  GCC `-std=c23` *does* error.  It that item in the standard just talking about there being no named vars you can access to read any parameters that got passed? Otherwise GCC and Clang would be deviating from the C11 standard, perhaps intentionally, but then what's C23 changing?

Comment: @PeterCordes You've misconstrued my comment. I was addressing the question that the OP asked. The question specifically asks whether *"`int main() {/*...*/}` is a valid **definition** for `main`"* Emphasis on **definition** added. Notice also the emphasis on **definition** in my comment. Your comment is about whether a **definition** with an empty argument list acts as a **prototype**. The answer to that question in C11 is "No".  In C23, the answer is "Yes".

Comment: @user3386109: Oh, you just meant in terms of being a valid definition and being compatible with a caller (like `_start`) that wants to call a main function taking 0 or 2 args.  Not in terms of how the definition acts as a declaration, which is the part that's not equivalent until C23.

Answer (score 20):

In C17 and earlier versions of the standard, `int main() { … }` does not provide a prototype for `main()` but is otherwise equivalent to `int main(void) { … }`.

In C23, `int main() { … }` does provide a prototype for `main()` and is fully equivalent, except for spelling, to `int main(void) { … }`.

The difference only matters if you call `main()` recursively — something that is allowed in C and disallowed in C++.  With `int main()` in C17 or earlier, a recursive call like `main(23, "elephants");` is allowed because there is no prototype specified for `main()` (assuming that the definition of `main()` is visible before the recursive call).  With `int main(void)`, that is not allowed because there is a prototype in scope that says "no arguments".

Note what is said in [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18721336/15168)  That has extensive discussions, including that the C17 and earlier standards use both `int main()` and `int main(void)` in their (non-normative) examples.  It also points out what Microsoft specifies for Windows systems and what Annex J "Common Extensions" mentions (both recognize `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)`).  Apple even has a fourth optional argument to `main()` — `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp, char **apple)` that behaves like `argv` or `envp`.  I need to update my answer for C23 sometime soon.

Comment: Hmm,  As I read "An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the function has no parameters." (C11 §6.7.6.3 14) says to me that `foo() { .... }`, as a function _definition_ that a later `foo(23, "elephants");` is an invalid call.  I would expect `int main() { ... }` and a later call like `main(23, "elephants");` to also be invalid.

Comment: _Side note:_ Why can you call `main` recursively in C but _not_ in C++? Although not super useful, I could devise a C program: `#include <stdio.h> int main(int argc,char **argv) { printf("%s: %s\n",argv[0],argv[argc - 1]); if (argc > 2) main(argc - 1,argv); return 0; }` Build it and run it with: `./program hello world goodbye galaxy` and get: `./program: galaxy ./program: goodbye ./program: world ./program: hello` Why won't this work with C++? It seems to be some arbitrary rule. What's the rationale for this rule?

Comment: @CraigEstey Say rather an _obsolete_ rule. Cfront-era C++ implementations injected code at the beginning of `main` to run global constructors, and that code was not idempotent, so recursively calling `main` would run the global constructors again and hilarity would ensue. I imagine the rule persists today largely because nobody in WG21 thinks it's important enough to bother changing.

Comment: @zwol Thanks [for knowing the history]. I was running out of space, so I couldn't add: It should be okay because any static/global C++ constructors/destructors will be called [once] from the `crt*.o` prolog/epilog.

Comment: When the C17 or earlier compiler encounters `int main() { … }`, the function is declared and defined, but not with a prototype.  It is declared like `int function();` — a function returning an `int` with an indeterminate (but not variadic) argument list.

Comment: @CraigEstey: MinGW puts a call to a `__main` init function at the top of `main:` in the asm even in C mode, I think instead of having their libc init stuff run from DLL on-load hooks.  Presumably it's idempotent at least in C mode, perhaps with an already-initialized check of a static flag.  [What library has the \_\_main function reference in gcc assembly output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45442279) / [How does GCC implement \_\_attribute\_\_((constructor)) on MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60971878) (GCC supports static-constructor functions even in C mode, so maybe not libc init)

Comment: @PeterCordes: They can't put their libc stuff in DLL on-load hooks because of `-static`. There's no such thing as an EXE on-load hook. Now why they didn't put that call in `crt0.o` (or its moral equivalent) I have no idea.

Answer (score 4):

All code fragments in the standard are considered to be examples, and, therefore, non-normative.

The normative requirement is what the text says: "[main] shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters[, or ...]". In C2023, `int main() { ... }` defines `main` with a return type of int and with no parameters, so it meets the requirement.

As pointed out in the comments on the question, C2011 had language that meant a *definition* `int main() { ... }` would have, under that standard, defined `main` with a return type of int and with no parameters, although a *declaration* `int main();` would *not* have declared `main` with no parameters. I cannot conveniently check C1999 or earlier from this computer.

Comment: Re “All code fragments in the standard are considered to be examples”: Code in examples are non-normative because examples are non-normative. There are fragments of code not in examples, used in exposition, and they are integral to the normative part of the standard. We cannot say the `int main(void) { /* ... */ }` in 5.1.2.2.1 is example code and not expositive code because then the `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }` would also be non-normative and then there is nothing in the normative standard that says the first parameter has type `int` and the second has type `char *[]`.

Comment: Notably the parts you quote from 5.1.2.2.1 are for _hosted systems_ - you are quoting the hosted system sub-chapter, which is only normative for strictly conforming _hosted_ programs. Whereas 6.7.6.3 is normative for all C programs. For example a C23 freestanding implementation might declare main as `void main ()` and that will be equivalent to `void main (void)`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil No, really, _all_ code fragments are non-normative examples. It does not actually say that anywhere in the text of the standard but this has been the consistent interpretation of the committee since before C1999. (It follows that the case you cite is a defect -- the requirement for the first parameter of `main` to be `int` and the second to be `char *[]` needs to be lifted to normative text.)

Comment: @Lundin That seems unrelated to the point made by my answer.

Comment: No it isn't, because the text you claim is normative isn't normative to C but normative to the sub category of hosted C programs. Though I realize you inherited this from the question itself.

Comment: @zwol: Re “No, really, all code fragments are non-normative examples”: There is no basis for this assertion, and it is impossible because the standard uses many code fragments in ways integral to the standard, as when it lists type specifier combinations in 6.7.2 2.

Comment: This is utter nonsense. The code in 5.1.2.2.1 1 is in the middle of a sentence. You are claiming the standard goes in and out of normative text multiple times inside a single sentence. And, with the code removed, the standard says nothing about the types of the parameters or how they are declared. (Further, the code sequences in this sentence are not code fragments. They are two complete programs.)

Comment: Re “the consistent interpretation of the committee since before C1999”: Show us these multiple interpretations of the committee of code fragments, other than in explicitly labeled examples, not being part of the normative text.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I no longer have access to a DR discussion and response archive from the 1990s, nor do I have the time to dig through it if I did. You're free to not believe me, but what I said is true.

Comment: So the normative text of 6.4.2.2 1 is “The identifier `__func__` shall be implicitly declared by the translator as if, immediately following the opening brace of each function definition, the declaration appeared, where *function-name* is the name of the lexically-enclosing function.” and not “The identifier `__func__` shall be implicitly declared by the translator as if, immediately following the opening brace of each function definition, the declaration `static const char __func__[] = "` *function-name* `";` appeared, where *function-name* is the name of the lexically-enclosing function.”

Comment: And 6.10.6 2 says “… the directive shall have one of the following forms whose meanings are described elsewhere: *on-off-switch*: one of”. This one is very similar to the `main` specification in 5.1.2.2.1; it is specifying forms that code may have and using a colon to introduce the display of those forms. If the code fragments are removed from it, it is grammatically incorrect gibberish.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, and even so, what I said is true.

Comment: What is the normative text of C 2018 6.10.6 2?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Assuming the text of C 2018 6.10.6p2 is substantively the same as N1570 6.10.6p2, then those are grammar rules, not code fragments. Grammar rules often look very much like code fragments, but the presence of the italicized *on-off-switch* is definitive here -- that's a nonterminal, so it has to be a grammar rule.

Comment: @EricPostpischil 6.4.2.2p1 is a better example for both your point and my point. The line beginning "static const char" _is_ a code fragment, and it _is_ non-normative. It _has_ to be non-normative, because if it were normative, the implementation would be required to make that implicit declaration _exactly as shown;_ it could not, for instance, (behave as-if) the declaration included `__attribute__((section(".rodata.function-names")))`. (1/2)

Comment: @EricPostpischil  _Yes, this does mean_ technically the standard _underspecifies_ the declaration instead of overspecifying it. That was the least bad option the committee found when responding to those DRs I mentioned. (2/2)

Comment: You’ve just misremembered code samples being non-normative from decades ago, witnessed by the lack of any statement or documentation to that effect. The rule is simply that examples are not part of the normative text of the standard, and many, if not most examples were largely code samples, and most code samples were examples. There never was a rule that any code sample anywhere in the standard is non-normative. Neither 5.1.2.2.1 1 nor other paragraphs have code just jammed into the middle of normative text. The code is an integral part of the sentence there, and it is normative text.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Like I said, you're free to not believe me, but what I said is true.

Answer (score 4):

Let's at first consider how the function `main` shall be declared according to the C17 Standard. The C17 Standard, section 6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes):

> 14 **An identifier list declares only the identifiers of the
> parameters of the function. An empty list in a function declarator
> that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the
> function has no parameters.** The empty list in a function declarator
> that is not part of a definition of that function specifies that no
> information about the number or types of the parameters is supplied.

That is empty parentheses can be used in a function definition when the function has an empty **identifier list**. But relative to the function `main` the Standard requires that it will be declared with a **parameter type list**.

From the C grammar:

> 5 If, in the declaration "T D1", D1 has the form

```
D ( parameter-type-list )
```

> or

```
D ( identifier-listopt )
```

> and the type specified for ident in the declaration "T D" is
> "derived-declarator-type-list T", then the type specified for ident is
> "derived-declarator-type-list function returning the unqualified
> version of T"

As it is seen the **parameter type list** may not be optional. It is the **identifier list** that may be optional.

Further (p. #10):

> 10 **The special case of an unnamed parameter of type void as the only
> item in the list specifies that the function has no parameters.**

That is the function `main` without parameters **shall be** declared with a **parameter list** that contains unnamed parameter of type `void`.

From the C17 Standard (5.1.2.2.1 Program startup):

> 1 The function called at program startup is named main. The
> implementation declares no prototype for this function. **It shall be
> defined with a return type of int and with no parameters**:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any
> names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are
> declared):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

> or equivalent;10) or in some other implementation-defined manner.

Now let's read the **footnote 10** that elaborates what means the word **equivalent**:

> 10)Thus, int can be replaced by a typedef name defined as int, or the
> type of argv can be written as char ** argv, and so on.

There is nothing said that the function declaration of the function `main` with an empty **parameter list** may be rewritten with a function declaration with an empty **identifier list**.

That is the Standard requires that the function `main` shall be declared with the **function prototype**. And examples of such declarations of `main` are presented in the quote provided above.

From the C17 Standard (6.9.1 Function definitions)

> Semantics
>
> 7 The declarator in a function definition specifies the name of the
> function being defined and the identifiers of its parameters. **If the
> declarator includes a parameter type list, the list also specifies the
> types of all the parameters; such a declarator also serves as a
> function prototype for later calls to the same function in the same
> translation unit.** If the declarator includes an identifier list,166)
> the types of the parameters shall be declared in a following
> declaration list. In either case, the type of each parameter is
> adjusted as described in 6.7.6.3 for a parameter type list; the
> resulting type shall be a complete object type.

Pay attention to that the verb ***shall*** in the C standard means the following

> 4. Conformance
>
> 1 **In this document, "shall" is to be interpreted as a requirement on
> an implementation or on a program**; conversely, "shall not" is to be
> interpreted as a prohibition.

What is changed in the C23 Standard relative to the declaration of `main`? **Nothing**! If you will read the **section 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup** of the C23 Standard Draft you will see that there are used the same text relative to the declaration of `main` without parameters.

Yes, now in the C23 Standard a function declaration with empty parentheses in the function declarator has another meaning. The **parameter type list** can be optional. The **identifier list** is excluded from function declarators. But the declaration of `main` satisfies the same requirements as in the C17 Standard. It **shall be declared** as written in the C23 Standard like

```
int main( void )
```

and even the footnote stays the same as in the C17 Standard. There is no a word that the function `main` may be declared like

```
int main()
```

in the section **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup** of the C23 Standard.

The form of the declaration of `main` with empty list of parameters was preserved in the C23 Standard in the same way as in the C17 Standard.

And `@zwol` mistakenly claims relative to the declaration of `main` that "All code fragments in the standard are considered to be examples, and, therefore, non-normative." The section **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup** of the both Standards, the C17 Standard and the C23 Standard, has normative description of how the function main **shall be** declared.

You should pay attention to that it will be a serious change in the normative description of `main` from preceding C Standards and the C23 Standard. And the C23 Standard should reflect that in its description "what documents, for all intents and purposes, have been applied to this draft (C23)". However in this list of documents nothing is said about changes in the requirements for declaration of the function `main`. I found only the following document that has some relation "N2432 Remove support for function definitions with identifier lists".

If to adopt that I am mistaken then as a consequence of that it may be concluded that the C23 Standard has a defect because this section was transferred from the C17 Standard without any changes but its meaning was changed. At least in the C23 Standard there should be added a note or a footnote in this section that clarifies changes relative to the previous C Standard.

Comment: Foot note 10 is not certainly an elaboration of "what means the word _equivalent_:"  It is a least an example of _equivalent_.  Other than that most of the answer is good.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica In any case the equivalence does not mean in C17 declaring main with an empty identifier list. It shall be declared with a parameter list including the empty parameter list.

Comment: Re “But relative to the function main the Standard requires that it will be declared with a **parameter type list**”: No such assertion appears in C 2017.

Comment: Re “As it is seen the **parameter type list** may not be optional. It is the **identifier list** that may be optional”: The grammar makes no such distinction. These two options for a *direct-declarator* establish that a *direct-declarator* may be “*direct-declarator* `(` *parameter-type-list* `)`, “*direct-declarator* `(` *identifier-list* `)`”, or “*direct-declarator* `(` `)`”. No distinction between whether `(` `)` means the *parameter-type-list* is missing or the *identifier-list* is missing is made either by the grammar rules or by the text of the standard.

Comment: Re “Further (p. #10):” /  10 **The special case of an unnamed parameter of type void as the only item in the list specifies that the function has no parameters.**” / “That is the function `main` without parameters **shall be** declared with a **parameter list** that contains unnamed parameter of type `void`.”: That passage from paragraph 10 says if the declarator has the form `D(void)`, then it specifies the function has no parameters, not that if the function has no parameters, its declarator must have the form `D(void)`, and it says nothing about what form `main` must have.

Comment: Re “the **footnote 10** that elaborates what means the word **equivalent**:”: It gives examples that help interpret but are not necessarily limiting. Re “There is nothing said that the function declaration of the function main with an empty **parameter list** may be rewritten with a function declaration with an empty **identifier list**”: The “and so on” is something said.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  You are wrong. You may not declare in C17 for example main with identifier list like int main( argc, argv ) int argc; char **argv; { }. The standard requires a parameter type list.  The words "shall be" means exactly shall be and not what you are imaging for yorself.

Comment: Focusing on the words “shall be” provides no information. There is zero dispute about whether `main` shall be declared as the standard says. There is only dispute about how the standard says `main` shall be declared. The standard says “It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and… or equivalent; or in some other implementation-defined manner.” If `int main() { /* ... */ }` is equivalent, then it satisfies the “shall be,” and so the only dispute is whether `int main() { /* ... */ }` is equivalent.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Parameter type list and identifier list are two different notions in function declarations. The trend is to use parameter type lists. And in the C23 declarations with identifier list were abondened. And it was already clear when the C17 Standard was adopted. Only it was decided to place a point relative this problem in the C23 Standard. And the C17 Standard requires that main was declared with a parameter type list. You should read the words "shall be" as main shall be declared with parameter type list: either with void or with two parameters int argc and char **argv.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Re “ And the C17 Standard requires that main was declared with a parameter type list”: No, it does not. Re: “You should read the words "shall be" as main shall be declared with parameter type list”: No, I should not, and neither should you.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I can not agree with you. There are explicitly shown how the function shall be declared. It shall be declared with parameter type lists.

Comment: Re “There are explicitly shown how the function shall be declared”: It is explicitly stated “or equivalent.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil Equivalent means how the parameters in the parameter list or the return type can be equivalently specified.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Actually it looks like  you are trying to invent something that is not present in the C17 Standard.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: No, “or equivalent” is present in the C 2017 standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, it presents. But it touches the function definitions of main with parameter type lists.

Answer (score 2):

> Are `int main()` and `int main(void)` equivalent prototypes in C23?

Yes, for function declarations.

C23 draft N1570 has the revised specification:

> For a function declarator without a parameter type list: the effect is as if it were declared with a parameter type list consisting of the keyword `void`. A function declarator provides a prototype for the function.  C23 § 6.7.6.3 13

I understand this to apply to all functions including `main()`.

The specifications about `main` do not restrict this.

Answer (score 0):

What is normative in the C standard:

- 6.7.6.3 is normative for all function declarators.
- The entry point for a C program is always a function in all C systems (see 5.1.2).
- If `main` is the entry point for a C program, then `int main ()` and `int main (void)` are equivalent as per C23 6.7.6.3.

Notably:

- Examples, including code examples are not *normative*. Neither are notes or foot notes. These are all examples of *informative* parts. For details check: [Are notes and examples in the core language specification of the C++ Standard non-normative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364398/are-notes-and-examples-in-the-core-language-specification-of-the-c-standard-no)
- Chapter 5.1.2.2.1 is only normative for strictly conforming *hosted* system programs. It bears no relevance for a general C program.
- As noted in the answer by @zwol, the parts in 5.1.2.2.1 that are normative (for hosted system programs) is the text "It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters" and not the example.
- Furthermore, 5.1.2.2.1 has the normative text "or equivalent". This was always meant for covering cases such as `int main (int foo, char* bar[])` or `int32_t main (void)` in a system where `int` ==  `int32_t`, and so on. Equivalent examples where only coding style or naming changes.

  As it happens, in C23 this "or equivalent" part will also apply to `int main (void)` vs `int main ()` since they are equivalent forms.
- 5.1.2.2.1 also has the text "or in some other implementation-defined manner".
  Similarly 5.1.2.1 for freestanding systems: "the name and type of the function called at program startup are
  implementation-defined".

  This means that as long as the function obeys the rules for how functions are declared, it can be named anything and declared in any manner, as long as this is documented by the implementation (compiler). However, a program relying on such will no longer be *strictly conforming* (C17 or C23 4 §5) since it relies on implementation-defined means; a freestanding program can therefore never be strictly conforming.

  It is however possible to in a *conforming* program (hosted/freestanding) to create a function with any name, return type or parameters as the entry point of the program, as long as the compiler documents and supports such.

  A program entry function with a format `int function_name()` still has to obey 6.7.6.3 however.

Common example of a conforming hosted system function (impl.defined):

```
int WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd);
```

Common example of a conforming freestanding system function (impl.defined):

```
void main (void);
```

Comment: Even if examples aren't normative, their existence would strongly suggest to me imply an intention and expectation that implementations will behave in the indicated fashion any time there isn't a very strong and compelling reason for doing otherwise.